# Pivotal Tracker API epics

Tags: ruby, api, sinatra, dashing, pivotaltracker

I'm currently putting together a dashboard for my team to display a number of pivotal tracker stats at a glance. I'm trying to implement a widget right now displays stats for stories on an epic-specific basis, but I don't see anything in the pivotal tracker api documentation for this. Does anyone know a way to select stories on the basis of the epic using the pivotal tracker api for ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure something out using two different methods. Whichever you use just depends on how you want to display your information.

Method One

```
@project = PivotalTracker::Project.find(your_project_id)
epicList = @project.stories.all(:labels => "your_epic_label")
```

Method Two

```
@project = PivotalTracker::Project.find(your_project_id)
@current = PivotalTracker::Iteration.current(@project)
epicList = @currnet.stories.select{ |s| s.labels.include? "your_epic_label"}
```